# Difference in entropy values for the same image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am finding the entropy value of an RGB image after histogram processing using the Y plane as follows:

```
i % the original image

y1=rgb2ycbcr(i);
y=y1(:,:,1);cb=y1(:,:,2);cr=y1(:,:,3);
he1=histeq(y);
r1=cat(3,he1,cb,cr);
r1=ycbcr2rgb(r1);

g1=rgb2gray(r1);
e1=entropy(g1);
```

Now I followed the procedure:

```
imwrite(r1,'temp1.jpg');
i2=imread('temp1.jpg');
g2=rgb2gray(i2);
e2=entropy(g2);
```

But now `e1` and `e2` are different.  Why it is so?

Answer (score 2):

You're writing the image `r1` to disk using the JPEG compression standard.  JPEG is **lossy**, which means that what is written to disk is **not** the same as what was originally stored in memory.  Though the images look perceptually the same, if you compared the colour values between corresponding pixels, the majority of them will be slightly different.  These slight differences is why the JPEG standard gives high compression ratios and thus smaller file sizes.

If you want to ensure that what you write to file is the same as what you read in, use a **lossless** compression standard, such as using PNG.  As such, change the destination filename so that you're using PNG, not JPEG:

```
imwrite(r1,'temp1.png'); %// Change
i2=imread('temp1.png');  %// Change
g2=rgb2gray(i2); 
e2=entropy(g2);
```